# How do I access and display images from an ionic app?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having issues with displaying images after running

```
ionic run ios
```

I have the default ionicframework template running with the sidemenu, and have not changed the app directory structure at all.

I have an inline css to specify a background image from an ng-repeat directive for categories.

```
style='background: url("{{category.img}}")
```

I've tried ../img/picture.jpg, /img/picture.jpg and img/picture.jpg. None seem to work. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a local:// image in ionic framework + cordova?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886437/how-to-display-a-local-image-in-ionic-framework-cordova)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, my project structure look like this:

```
/www/
    /images/
    /views/page.html
    index.html
```

and in `page.html` img links was: `<img src="images/image.png" ../>` and it worked for both web and mobile build.

Hope this helps.