# ionic doesn't load images

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

In my application I have some local images. I can see my images when test in google developer tools with `ionic serve` and even in genymotion simulator with android 4.4.4 and 4.2.2. but when I install my app on real android device ( I try on Samsung Galaxy S3 and Samsung Galaxy Ground Neo) I can't see my images.

My folder structure is like this:

- www

  - index.html
  - app

    - book

      - book.html
      - images

        - icon.png

and in my `book.html` I try the following url for loading image:

```
    <img src="app/book/images/icon.png">
    <img src="../../images.icon.png">
```

I also move icon.png to root folder inside index.html and try this:

```
  <img src="icon.png">
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I remember the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267378/how-do-i-access-and-display-images-from-an-ionic-app/27267507#27267507

Comment: if you're rendering book.html then it should look for path `images/icon.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that HTML structure works is that is that you always need to call your files relative to your current file. For example, if your structure looks like:

```
- index.html
- folder
    -image.png
```

You would need to say `src="image.png"`. So in your case, you do not have to reference the root directory (folder). You can just say `images/icon.png`. To reference an upper level folder (if it were in the root), you could say `../../icon.png`, using `../` for each subsequent folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. my images are stored in  `www\assets\images`. I was using the path `../../assets/images/myimg.png` and worked in ripple but not when deployed to my android device.

The **solution** that worked for me was removing the relative path and using `assets/images/myimg.png`